# How to count empty line using grep

Tags: text-processing, files, grep, search

I have a text file. Some lines contain text while others do not (just empty line without any spaces or characters:

```
123

// comment
45
```

As you can see, there is a line above `//comment`. If I want to count the times such line exist in my file, how can I grep them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can grep empty lines with `grep '^$' file` and count the lines with `wc -l`. Combined it's:

```
grep '^$' file | wc -l
```

or even shorter with `grep`'s count option `-c` or `--count`

```
grep -c '^$' file
```

Comment: `grep -cv . file` where we reverse the match.